# google smart home limit on number of devices returned from sync

Tags: actions-on-google

When Google issues a Sync to discover our SmartHome devices, we can some times return a high number (could be a 1000). It appears that if we return 60 devices or more they are not discovered. If return 50, they are discovered. Is there a known limit on the number of devices we can return?

-Rich

Comment: Does it take too long to return 60 items from the server, creating a timeout?

Comment: The more devices we add the longer it takes for the Google Home app to populate the devices. It seems like Google might be timing out somewhere. But we have verified that our server is returning all the devices immediately in our JSON response. But at 60 devices, we never get any devices listed in the Home app. I read somewhere that it should handle over 1000 devices, so not sure what is going on.